# Mupx deployment with Meteor.js fails when "Installing Docker"

Tags: meteor, ubuntu-14.04, meteor-up

I have Ubuntu 14.04, developing on it and want to have a test server on the same computer. It is ran in Virtual Box.

So I followed all the steps on Github for Mupx setup and watched the video that Meteor.js guide told me to watch it. When I get to command:

```
mupx setup
```

it shows me the screen with the error:

```
nejc@nejc-vb:~/Meteor Projects/CSGO/CSGO-deploy$ mupx setup

Meteor Up: Production Quality Meteor Deployments
------------------------------------------------
Configuration file : mup.json
Settings file      : settings.json

“ Checkout Kadira!
  It's the best way to monitor performance of your app.
  Visit: https://kadira.io/mup ”


Started TaskList: Setup (linux)
[my_public_IP] - Installing Docker

events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: Timed out while waiting for handshake
    at null._onTimeout (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mupx/node_modules/nodemiral/node_modules/ssh2/lib/client.js:138:17)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout [as ontimeout] (timers.js:121:15)
```

My mup.json file looks like this:

```
{
  // Server authentication info
  "servers": [
    {
      "host": "my_public_IP",
      "username": "nejc",
      "password": "123456",
      // or pem file (ssh based authentication)
      // WARNING: Keys protected by a passphrase are not supported
      //"pem": "~/.ssh/id_rsa"
      // Also, for non-standard ssh port use this
      //"sshOptions": { "port" : 49154 },
      // server specific environment variables
      "env": {}
    }
  ],

  // Install MongoDB on the server. Does not destroy the local MongoDB on future setups
  "setupMongo": true,

  // Application name (no spaces).
  "appName": "CSGO",

  // Location of app (local directory). This can reference '~' as the users home directory.
  // i.e., "app": "~/Meteor Projects/CSGO",
  // This is the same as the line below.
  "app":  "/home/nejc/Meteor Projects/CSGO",

  // Configure environment
  // ROOT_URL must be set to your correct domain (https or http)
  "env": {
    "PORT": 80,
    "ROOT_URL": "http://my_public_IP"
  },

  // Meteor Up checks if the app comes online just after the deployment.
  // Before mup checks that, it will wait for the number of seconds configured below.
  "deployCheckWaitTime": 30,

  // show a progress bar while uploading. 
  // Make it false when you deploy using a CI box.
  "enableUploadProgressBar": true
}
```

Comment: I think when I installed/configured Mup/Mupx I had to install Docker manually on my server first.  It should start a daemon process for Docker.  This may be what the timeout is complaining about.

Comment: @CodeChimp thanks for the comment and I tried it and it still does not work.

Comment: I ran into your same issue with mupx on mac, I eventually got it to work by removing the "sshOptions": { "port" : 49154 } part, but it looks like you already have the commented out.